# SQL SUM label summary

Tags: sql, sas

Is there any possibility in SQL to add a ROW with a summary MEAN, for example, sum and average. For example, something like this

```
|  2021-01 | 16             | 
|  2020-12 | 15             |  
| -------- | -------------- |
| SUM      | 31             |
| Mean     | 15.5           |
```

My code:

```
proc sql;
   create table diff as
       select today.policy_vintage
            , today.number_policy as POLICY_TODAY
            , prior.number_policy as POLICY_PRIOR
            , today.number_policy - prior.number_policy as DIFFERENCE
            , avg(prior.number_policy) as POLICY_MEAN_PRIOR
            , today.number_policy - mean(prior.number_policy) as DIFFRENCE_MEAN
       from policy_vintage_weekly today
       LEFT JOIN
            (select *
             from _work.POLICY_VINTAGE_WEEKLY
             where run_date < today()
             having run_date = max(run_date)
            ) prior
       ON today.policy_vintage = prior.policy_vintage
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Generally speaking, these aggregates values are not stored but calculated dynamically, as they might change when related values evolve (add / update or remove rows). On top of that, you would have duplicates, as the aggregates will be solved in each row used for the calculation. I you don't, they will be "alone in their rows" with no real meaning (how will you retrieve them later on?)

Comment: I would like it to always count given columns no matter what is sum (today) sum (prior) in them

Comment: I understand, and then you will have a complicated constraint to maintain it up to date! Why don't you just calculate these values when you need them? I do not knows how your database is built, but it's not in the main conception principles to store this kind of values

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want. To mee it looks like you just want to retrieve monthly sums and then the total sum and the average monthly sum. But then in your query it looks completely different. The table has weekly data from its name and you don't look at months at all. You look at single days instead and try to select the previous day's data along? At ast you say you want to add a column, but what you are showing is not columns but rows. Please clarify which of all these things you actually want and which not. Sample data might help.

Comment: What is your DBMS? Answers on SQL requests can heavily depend on the DBMS you are using. Please always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS.

Comment: I look more in detail to your example, it seems your table is not really stored, but dynamically calculated, am I wrong? IS it a kind of stored procedure (it looks like being SAS)?

Comment: Use PROC MEANS and the types/ways statement to get the different levels included.

Answer (score 2):

If your table contains:

| Date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-00 | 16 |
| 2020-12-00 | 15 |

Than this query will get you the result you want:

```
SELECT * FROM test.test
union
select "SUM", sum(value) from test.test
union
select "Mean", avg(value) from test.test;

+------------+---------+
| date       | value   |
+------------+---------+
| 2021-01-00 | 16.0000 |
| 2020-12-00 | 15.0000 |
| SUM        | 31.0000 |
| Mean       | 15.5000 |
+------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

Tested on Mariadb 10.6.4

But having said that, it would be more something that is calculated in some client software you are using.

Comment: Correct... but if there are some aggregation constraints, the need for totals and subtotals, it will not work. I do not talk about performances! But you answered the question like it is XD

Comment: aggregations can always be grouped with `GROUP BY`. Or for more advanced results look at [window functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions-overview/)